# Setting up a simple function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, anaconda

I'm trying to write a function which takes my input as amount of dicerolls, gets a random number between 1,6 for that amount of dicerolls, and then appends these to a list.

I've tried different return messages, but I can't seem to to make it append to a list, and can't really think of what else I can do with my code.

```
terninger = []
def terning_kast(antal_kast = int(input("Hvor mange terningekast? "))):
    for x in range(antal_kast, 0, -1):
        resultat = random.randint(1, 6)
        terninger.append(resultat)
    return resultat
print(terninger)
```

I'm expecting the code to append the random number 1,6 into my list above (terninger), but I'm only receiving an empty list.

Comment: You never *call* that function...

Comment: I'm still very new to Python, what do you mean?

Comment: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to call your function => `terning_kast()`

```
terninger = []
def terning_kast(antal_kast = int(input("Hvor mange terningekast? "))):
    for x in range(antal_kast, 0, -1):
        resultat = random.randint(1, 6)
        terninger.append(resultat)
    return resultat

print('before', terninger)
terning_kast() # this is the line which you have missed
print('after', terninger)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few points that you need to correct in your logic. Meantime, following is probably that you want.

```
import random as rnd

def terning_kast(count):
    terninger = []
    for x in range(count, 0, -1):
        resultat = rnd.randint(1, 6)
        terninger.append(resultat)
    return terninger

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cnt = input("Hvor mange terningekast? ")
    if cnt.isdigit():
        print(terning_kast(int(cnt)))
    else:
        print("Invalid entry")
```

1. In order to use the random module, first you need to import it into your module.
2. Though you are appending the generated random number to list, you never attempt to return that list. What you are returning is the last instance of result from the randint(x,y) function call.
3. You are defining your function as part of your module/script. In order to execute that function, you must either call it within module or import it to some other module. If you look at my example the `if` `__name__ == "__main__":` instruct the python interpreter to run your script if you were to execute from same module. If you were to consume this module (importing) from some other then you don't need to mentioned this  `if` `__name__ == "__main__":`